# Difference between Google Interactive Media Ads(IMA) and Google AdMob

Tags: admob, ads, google-ima

I read about **Google IMA** and **Google AdMob** and as per my understanding both are used to used to deliver Ads. The differences are that:

1) Google `IMA` is generally used when video Ads are required which I believe is not supported by AdMob.
2) `AdMob` is generally used when only Banner Ads are required, as it is simpler to integrate than IMA SDK.
3) In case of `IMA`, a **VAST server** is required to return Ads, but in case of `AdMob`, an account with `AdMob` is need to create the AdUnits.

So my questions are:

1) Is my understanding regarding the differences correct?
2) `IMA` appears to be a superset of `AdMob` in terms to features since it can also support banner Ads. Is that correct?
3) Is there any other reason to use `AdMob` instead of `IMA` apart from simplicity of integration and not requiring a VAST server?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To address your questions, let me first talk about what each SDK does in short.  If you have any questions, feel free to ask:

- The **Mobile Ads SDK** (Android, iOS, and a plugin for Unity) serves ads (banners, interstitials [static or video], [rewarded videos](https://admob.googleblog.com/2016/03/mediate-rewarded-video-ads-with-admob.html), and [native ads](https://admob.googleblog.com/2016/05/making-native-ads-better-for-app-developers.html)).  Ads can be served from AdMob, DoubleClick for Publishers, and [others](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/mediation-networks) via what is called [mediation](https://support.google.com/admob/answer/3063564?hl=en).  For ad networks not on that list, you can write a [custom event](https://firebase.google.com/docs/admob/android/custom-events) to manually mediate with it.
- The **IMA** (Interactive Media Ads) **SDK** (Android, iOS, HTML5, Flash, and the mobile web) serves video-based ads.  Ads can be linear (pre-roll, mid-roll, and/or post-roll), non-linear (overlay banners sitting at the bottom of the video player screen), or [companion](https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/docs/companions/) ("banners" that accompany your video ad - these are distributed outside the video player area).  These ads are mostly served from DoubleClick for Publishers and AdSense.

Now, let me address your points in details:

> Google IMA is generally used when video Ads are required which I believe is not supported by AdMob

This is correct in a way.  Video ads are also supported by AdMob, as long as they are in the format of an interstitial.  You might have seen an interstitial (a full-screen ad) with a video playing in the upper portion of the ad.  That is a video ad in AdMob's sense.  Some developers use both SDKs together in their app to serve both interstitial and video ads!

> AdMob is generally used when only Banner Ads are required, as it is simpler to integrate than IMA SDK

As I noted earlier, the Mobile Ads SDK serves a whole lot more ad formats than just banner ads.  Out of the box, both SDKs should be simple to integrate.  You can check out our GitHub samples!

> In case of IMA, a VAST server is required to return Ads, but in case of AdMob, an account with AdMob is need to create the AdUnits

Correct.

> IMA appears to be a superset of AdMob in terms to features since it can also support banner Ads. Is that correct?

Not quite.  I wouldn't refer to IMA as being a superset of AdMob / the Mobile Ads SDK.  Each SDK serves its own kind of ads, so depending on your monetizing need, you can pick the one you prefer (if not both).