# Difference between Google IMA and GMA

Tags: ios, ads

I am looking to add ads into an iOS app via 'DFP' (Double Click For Publishers). It seems DFP is a nebulous concept with different meanings to different people. These ads (video) are to typically be displayed before content is showed on some semi regular basis, but could also be intermixed in the UI.

Searching for: "dfp sdk ios" leads directly to:
https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/dfp/ios/quick-start
(apparently a synonym for **GMA**)

But I am also told Interactive Media Ads (**IMA**) may actually be what I should use:
https://developers.google.com/interactive-media-ads/

They both advertize DFP support, and seem to both have video ad capability.

I would prefer the most general solution, for more control if possible (eg: methods, feedback, display area), or if I decide I need to put different 'types' of ads in different places (whatever a type would be in the given sdk).

I have no visibility into the configuration / server side so this may be why the decision is so fuzzy to me.

---

This question is more about types of ad services which I would hope are encapsulated away from developers by the library:
[Difference between Google Interactive Media Ads(IMA) and Google AdMob](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37239554/difference-between-google-interactive-media-adsima-and-google-admob)

This seems to be designed for marketers with no technical explanation:
https://developers.google.com/ads/#apps